# Diagonalize a not diagonalizable matrix??

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, eigenfunctions

I've just found a very strange exercise: from a 3x3 Matrix the eigenvalues are found to be 2: 1 with multiplicity 1 and the other with multiplicity 2; trying to find the kernel of the matrix A-LAMBDA I for the eigenvalue with multiplicity 2, it has dimension 1; the solution of the exercise otherwise, after have found the eigenvector from this matrix, calculates the square of A-LAMBDA I and then finds the eigenvector from this matrix and at the end uses this vector and the previous eigenvector to build a base for this eigenspace. What does this mean? How can this work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what their name was